# Noise Matching transformer

Tags: transformer, noise, impedance, impedance-matching, snr

I'd like to use a transformer to improve the performance of our SR5184 preamp.

The [signal recovery SR5184 is an ultra low noise preamplifier](http://signalrecovery.com/our-products/preamplifiers/5184.aspx). It has 0.8 nV/ √Hz input noise and a bandwidth of 0.5 Hz - 1 MHz. It's noise figure is shown below.
[image: Noise Figure]

We use it to amplify nV signals of a cryogenic low impedance load (< 1 Ohm with leads).
The frequency range of interest is a few Hz to at least 400 kHz. Even a turn ratio of 1:10 would boost the SNR significantly.

The Question is:

- Are there commercially available transformers that match the requirements?
- Which companies could manufacture them?
- Is that even possible with room temperature transformers?

Update:

I found some transformers covering an even larger frequency range, e.g.:

- [J2100A](https://www.picotest.com/products_J2100A.html) injection transformer (1 Hz - 5 Mhz; ratio 1:1)
- [J2101A](https://www.picotest.com/products_J2101A.html) injection transformer (10 Hz - 45 MHz; ratio 1:1)
- [LL1575](http://www.lundahl.se/wp-content/uploads/datasheets/1575.pdf) CCTV isolation transformer (20 Hz - 11 MHz; ratio 1:1)

Sadly they just have a 1:1 ratio. But I guess with a bandwidth reduction an increase in turn ratio should be possible.

Comment: The problem with a transformer is likely to be the wide bandwidth requirement : it's difficult to make a transformer reasonably flat across the audio band (20Hz to 20kHz) but not impossible : another decade on the frequency response is asking quite a lot. By the way, did you mean you wanted to match a 1 ohm source impedance up to the ideal (1 to 10k) for this amp?

Comment: What's the device you are looking at?  With such a low impedance  could you think about doing a current measurement?  Ask SR if they have a different front end for the lock-in?

Comment: @George Herold We are measuring noise spectra of driven magnetic structures.

Comment: @Drummond Yes thats what I meant.

Comment: Signal Recovery Model 1900 transformer

Comment: @Guest The model 1900 has an extremely narrow bandwidth. It's not very useful for my applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Less than one ohm with leads-  I imagine that represents a big thermal load on the cryostat.

Yes, a room-temperature transformer can make a tremendous improvement. The important thing is that the Johnson-Nyquist noise in the windings does not contribute too much noise, so there needs to be enough copper.

There are commercial products that go up to the 10s of kHz, with noise in the 100pV sqrtHz range, I'm not aware of higher frequency units (but we have a product with a custom transformer optimized for 100's of kHz). Your desired frequency range is extremely wide- it would be easier to deal with in two ranges.

Comment: The cooling power is no problem. We're not at mK. I would prefer not having to build one by myself. Any suggestions where to look?

Comment: Try Stanford Research